# How to link to a certain part of a website?

Tags: links

Say I am reading an article on the New York Times or VICE and I want to send a link to my brother. Is there a way to link to a specific part of the article or site, much in the same way that you can link to a specific point in a YouTube video ie. by appending a tag to the URL?

Is there another way of linking and referring to a specific point on a website?

Comment: What if the page doesn't have id attributes anywhere near the part you want to share?

Comment: Yes there is (now). See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page/72400036#72400036). Previously, we could link to a precise spot on the webpage if there was an ID close by... But this new feature (as of Feb 2020) allows one to specify a text string. See the link for more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can link to any HTML element that has an `id` attribute set, by appending `#id's_value` to the end of the page's URL. This, of course, requires two things: 1) the specific point to which you want to link has an element with the `id` set; and 2) you search it in the page's source.

This is how a Wikipedia article's **Contents** links work, for instance, but I don't think it will work on the NY Times articles, since the entire article is made of paragraphs (`<p>`) that don't have the `id` attribute set.

On the other hand, there are apps like [Citebite](http://citebite.com/), that do exactly what you want.

> **Link directly to quotes in Web pages.**
>   Paste a chunk of text and the URL of the page containing the text and in return get a link that opens directly to your selection and highlights it.

Comment: An example would be helpful

Answer (score 5):

It's possible, for example, if the site uses HTML anchors. Then, you can use a link like `http://nyt.com/2012/02/19/story#heading3`.

This will automatically scroll the browser to the anchor named `heading3`.

For example, my answer's anchor URL is `http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24013/how-to-link-to-a-certain-part-of-a-website/24015#24015`

If you can't find an anchor on the site, then you have to look at the HTML code (e.g. right click -> Inspect Element).